# Data replication in alfresco - custom requirements

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Here is my scenario.Whenever i want to replicate contents in alfresco to different environment ,I should have the option of choosing files in my content to replicate. Is there anyway where I can put a custom button in alfresco which does the above operation (say "publish to abc environment").Or we have an inbuilt option to choose contents during replication in alfresco.Any links to examples would be helpful

Comment: You can improve your question by providing a link to the replication section of the Alfresco manual. Also, have you tried anything to solve your problem?

Comment: You can chose and then transfer a specific folder. But if you want to selectively choose what to transfer, then you have no other choice than work with Script.